# How to generate a query report to a PDF file using a GridDB Container

Tags: griddb

I have stored my database in a GridDB container; however, I need to generate a report from my pandas queries. The first line of the PDF report is a text containing a "title, date report was
generated, date and time submitted and my name". The rest of the PDF contains the "title" of the database and the "result" from my pandas query. Is there a possible way of exporting my
queries to PDF and writing those texts at the top of the generated PDF file? In the code below, I have used datetime and time modules to get the current date and time and the function returns the header text I want for the PDF. The second function – export() would take in the result of the
SQL query, the header text, and the output source, then export it into a PDF file, returning the source of the output file:

```
import datetime
import griddb_python as griddb
import time
import pandas as pd
#...
sql_statement = (“SELECT * FROM AppData WHERE date IN (‘29/9/2021’,
‘30/9/2021’, ‘1/10/2021’)”)
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(sql_statement, cont)
def header_text():
title = “Report for New Users”
dnow, c_time = date.today(), time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
c_date = dnow.strftime("%m_%d_%y")
header_text = f“””
{title}
On: {c_date}
By: {c_time}
Report By: Mary Williams
“””
return header_text
def export(output_src, header_text, query):
#Code goes here
#...
return output_src
header_txt = header_text()
output_source = export(“C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\ReportToday.pdf”, header_txt,
sql_query)
```